# JSON object recieved from api property returns undefined

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express, shopify

For the project that I am working on, I am using the Shopify API which allows you to retrieve products and other information from your store to be retrieved in the format of a JSON object. I was able to successfully get the JSON object from the API, however when I try to access a property of the JSON object, it returns undefined. I have looked at a couple of articles that I will refrence below, but the problem for those users were things such as needing to use:

```
JSON.parse()
```

for a JSON object enclosed by strings which is not my probelem, I have tried a few other work arounds as well but with no luck, I originally thought that the problem was that my code needed to use an "Async/Await" function in order to wait for a response from the API, but I then realized that wouldn't make sense considering I can recieve the whole JSON object itself with no problems.

When I use:

```
request.get(url, {headers})
.then( result => {
console.log(result); // Only accessing object itself
});
```

I recieve the JSON object response correctly with no error like this:

```
     {"products":[{"title":"Test Product 1","body_html":"This is a product that is being tested for retrieval!",
"product_type":"","created_at":"2018-08-21T17:49:07-07:00","handle":"test-product-1","updated_at":"2018-08-21T17:49:07-07:00","published_at":"2018-08-21T17:48:19-07:00","template_suffix":null,"tags":"",
"published_scope":"web","variants":[{"title":"Default Title","price":"5.00","sku":"","position":1,"inventory_policy":"deny",
"compare_at_price":null,"fulfillment_service":"manual","inventory_management":null,"option1":"Default Title","option2":null,"option3":null,
"created_at":"2018-08-21T17:49:07-07:00","updated_at":"2018-08-21T17:49:07-07:00","taxable":true,"barcode":"",
"grams":99790,"image_id":null,"inventory_quantity":1,"weight":220.0,"weight_unit":"lb","old_inventory_quantity":1,
"requires_shipping":true,}],"options":[{"name":"Title","position":1,"values":["Default Title"]}],"images":[],"image":null}]}
```

However when I use this, the JSON object property returns undefined:

```
request.get(url, {headers})
    .then( result => {
    console.log(result.products[0]); // Accessing the first item in JSON "products" array
    });
```

Articles I have already checked out:

[cannot access json object property returns undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38704166/cannot-access-json-object-property-returns-undefined)

[JSON object returns undefined value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23507807/json-object-returns-undefined-value)

[JSON objects returns undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25833384/json-objects-returns-undefined)

Would anyone be able to explain my error or why this is happening? I am more than happy to edit my question to include any code/information that might be helpful.

Thanks in advance,
Michael

Comment: Its possible the result is not the json, but a response object that has the json inside it.  So maybe you need something like `result.body` or `result.json()`.  What do you get when you try to log the whole `result` object?

Comment: @JimPerris I updated my question to reflect the actual API response I receive. When I log the result itself, that's the exact response that I get

Comment: you could try adding Items as in Items.products[0]

Comment: @DavidWhite What exactly do you mean? Is that the same as my attempt that goes: result.products[0]?

Comment: yes. I am not sure what result is doing next to products, maybe result = Items.products[0] or result=products[0].

Comment: @DavidWhite Just out of curiosity, in your suggestion result = Items.products[0]. Where does the word Items come from? None of my json properties are named items

Comment: I see Items in most of the JSON I work on. It may not be relevent to your use case.

Comment: if the JSON is not properly formed then JSON methods may not work. Stringify on a bigger dataset like this cumbersome... each dataset is separated by "variable"[ and ends with a ]. regular expressions could well make light work of this once stringyfied...

Comment: Paste the JSON into jsonlint.com, you'll see that it reports an error. There's an extra comma after `"requires_shipping": true`. This is allowed in JavaScript, but not in JSON.

Comment: @DavidWhite It ended up[ being related to what you said, I needed to stringy the data in order to access it, thank you! I gave you the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
console.log("data:", JSON.stringify(result.products[0], null, 2));
```

console.log to print the result to your console. Use Chrome and developer tools and you will see a console option - excellent for debugging.

JSON.stringify turns the JSON data into something you can see and read. You can convert the data and then split as you need this way too.

OK, a second answer. I can't check this, as I don't have your JSON data, however, I would try something that would likely resemble this...

data.Items[0].field

if the data is not correctly formatted then take the stringify approach and split it out. Otherwise, consider this:

```
products":[{"title":"Test Product 1"

variable = products[0].title;
```

I would tend to use a function to pull all the data out in one shot.

```
function Getv(data){    global.myApp.v = JSON.stringify(data, null, 2); }
```

then I might run this...

```
 Getv(data.Items[0]); let splitData = global.myApp.v.split('\"'); let vCount= splitData.length;
```

Comment: sometimes the stringify is just a crude and fast way to get at the data, there are other ways. I will give you another answer

Comment: Sorry about changing them, I replaced them with the answer you gave me and I receive the following error: TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Comment: Thank you for this response! I am able to retrieve the data, however its stored into an array in about 100 different sections, its retrieves it, just chops it up a lot more than intended! I'm currently trying to find a way to fix that

Answer (score 0):

if the object returns like this it wouldn't work because it's missing a colon after "products" identifier. like Luca said it's not a valid JSON response

Comment: I updated my question to the actual API JSON response

Comment: I tried to run the data you sent as a script and I was able access to data.products[0] even data.products[0].title.

Comment: What did you use to access it?

Comment: access the data? I made a get request to a node listener which returned the data you've sent.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var resultJson = JSON.parse(result);

console.log(resultJson.products[0].varname);
```